# In Vim, how to insert a word after regex match at the begining of next line

Tags: vim

A word needs to be injected at the beginning of each `line 1`. I tried the following, but obviously it does not work `:g/^=/+1i/myword/`

File structure:

```
===============
line 1
line 2
...
===============
line 1
line 2
...
```

Comment: Is `ed` relevant for this question?

Comment: I was under the impression ed commands are a subset of vim and my question is related to it because of the relative address part (+1 line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
:g/^=/+1normal Imyword
```

Note that `+1` could be shortened to `+` and `:normal` to `:norm`:

```
:g/^=/+norm Imyword
```

See `:help :insert` for why your method couldn't work and `:help :normal`.

Comment: I'm also a big fan of `:put` and and the expression register. e.g. `:g/^=/pu='myword'`

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it by `:s` command：

```
:%s/=\n\zs/myword
```

`\zs` denotes that preceding pattern is zero-width, which is just used as a matching condition, and won't be captured.