# Insert new paragraph in +norm Imyword,{new paragraph}

Tags: vim

**My question is related to that one:**
*[1]: [In Vim, how to insert a word after regex match at the begining of next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032758/in-vim-how-to-insert-a-word-after-regex-match-at-the-begining-of-next-line/.)*

My question is
***how to insert a new paragraph(line) in the construction like that after*** `I`

```
:g/kd392Sz\S\S/+norm I"b391c22e","6zed59ce","d3bcd91753","82xC4els3","8f6lsiz61",
```

for vim inserting the stroke `"b391c22e","6zed59ce","d3bcd91753","82xC4els3","8f6lsiz61",` as one line text but i need to insert it as:

```
"b391c22e",
"6zed59ce",
"d3bcd91753",
"82xC4els3",
"8f6lsiz61",
```

Comment: Does not the original answer valid for your question? Please be specific about what you want to achieve and give concrete examples.

Comment: Your two examples are separated by "or" despite being exactly identical. What are you trying to do? Give us a before/after example.

Comment: `:g/a892c23o78\S\S/+norm I"jkde32Xs","32Dasez","de221szf",`
for now vim inserting `"jkde32Xs","32Dasez","de221szf",` as a line text but I need to insert that part as 3 lines with {line break} after comma
```
"jkde32Xs",{line break}
"32Dasez",{line break}
"de221szf",{line break}
```

Comment: In your question, please.

Comment: The current line is missing from your "after" sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `:help :normal`:

```
:g/pattern/norm O"one",^M"two",^M"three",^M"four",^M"five",
```

Note: the `^M` is a literal `<CR>` that you obtain by pressing `<C-v>` followed by `<CR>` so the exact command is:

```
:g/pattern/norm O"one",<C-v><CR>"two",<C-v><CR>"three",<C-v><CR>"four",<C-v><CR>"five",
```

With `:help :put`:

```
:g/pattern/put!=['\"one\",','\"two\",','\"three\",','\"four\",','\"five\",']
```

With `:help :s`:

```
:g/pattern/s/^/"one",\r"two",\r"three",\r"four",\r"five",\r
```